# How to know if the Flow Drain has completed?

Tags: devops, corda

Can I know if there are any indicators in my node to check if the flow drain is complete, so that I can carry on with the upgrades?

Answer (score 0):

The number of current in-progress/suspended flows on a node is given by:

```
CordaRPCOps.stateMachinesFeed.snapshot.size
```

You can also see the in-progress/suspended flows via the shell using:

```
run stateMachinesSnapshot
```

Corda 4 will introduce `CordaRPCOps.pendingFlowsCount` to make checking this easier.